# Apply CSS rule to all element with specific class but the last

Tags: css

In the below code, how can I apply CSS rules to all of an specific Class `.box` but NOT to the last one?

I already tried `:not(:last-of-type)` and `:not(:last-child)` but they are not doing the job

```css
.box{
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  padding:12px;  
}
.box:not(:last-of-type){
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
.box:not(:last-child){
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
<div class="box">Box 4</div>
```

Comment: So here's the actual answer. (Question closed so can't add as answer.) Stackoverflow (and jsfiddle) append extra, hidden elements `body`. `:last-child` ends up targetting these added elements and, since they're hidden, the style appears to have an unexpected effect. CodePen doesn't do this so your example works fine [there](http://codepen.io/ouroborus/pen/xgxyJv). Some of the answers suggest using a wrapper element which, of course, helps mitigate this issue, but doesn't say anything about why it's an issue.

Comment: @BoltClock This isn't a duplicate of that. While it talks about `:last-child`, both this question and its answers talk about a different issue.

Comment: @Ouroborus: The question is the same in principle: the asker wants to apply styles to (all but) the last element with a specific class, for which there isn't any other solution but to modify the HTML. This is true regardless of whether there are any hidden elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try wrapping it with a parent element and try applying the styles as below

check this snippet

```css
.box {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.box:last-of-type {
  border:none ;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

or

you can use last-child as

```css
.box {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.box:last-child {
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The final rule should be `.box:last-child { border-bottom:none; }`. Shouldn't override things that don't need to be overridden. `.box:last-child` has a higher specificity than `.box` and so doesn't need to use `!important`.

Comment: yaa thats right:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.box {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.box:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `:not(:last-child)` wrap your divs in another div. The problem is otherwise browser can't identify which one is last child.

```css
.box{
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  padding:12px;  
}

.box:not(:last-child){
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

It's not suggestible to use overwriting of styles by giving styles to all and then giving another set of styles for `last-child` like giving `border: 1px` to `.box` and giving `border: none;` to `.box:last-child`. This is overwriting styles

Comment: Isn't `body` a container? So the last `.box` would be `:last-child` of `body`.

Comment: Yes. It's an exception. If you want to use `:last-child` or `:not(:last-child)`, it should be wrapped inside a wrapper otherthan body.
Try editing my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr4zmhqt/1/)

Comment: I looked into it. It's not an exception, just a particular quirk of Stackoverflow snippets. SO appends a `script` element to the snippet body and so that counts as `:last-child` of `body` rather than the intended element.

Comment: Ohh thanks. But I think preferably better to wrap in a div right?

Comment: Depends. `:not(:last-child)` is a weird construct anyway. If you just need to solve this problem then, yes, wrapping is the best solution.